# Format a multi-selection People Picker SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, multi-select

Issue is with fields in my SharePoint online list I am able to use the drop down to format the fields as desired. However when I try to format a field that is multi select for a people picker it opens up in JSON advance mode. Does anyone know how to format to be orange for this type of field?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this json format to turn the people picker（multi select）column be orange.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField.title",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "#FFA500",
    "color": "white"
  }
}
```

The rendering is as follows:

[image]

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Hi @David Lee,I am checking the status of this case. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.
If you have any update about this issue, please feel free to post back.

Comment: Did my response answer your question? If I misunderstand something, please let me know! If there is any other assistance i can provide, please feel free to let me know, i will do our best to help you.